# google cloud messaging for chrome receive error code 403 forbidden

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, messaging, google-cloud-messaging

I am in process of developing a Chrome extension program featuring google cloud messaging for chrome to push message to the instancess of my Chrome extension.

When try to push message to GCM Server, I receive below unsuccessful response  as below;

```
> POST /gcm_for_chrome/v1/messages HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 133
>
* upload completely sent off: 133 out of 133 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Mon, 15 Apr 2013 19:49:24 GMT
< Expires: Mon, 15 Apr 2013 19:49:24 GMT
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Server: GSE
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
}
```

Anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Thank you in advance.
Burin H.

Comment: It says "Access Not Configured." Have you fixed that? Don't post it here, but do you have a Client ID? http://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging.html#clientid You haven't said much about how you constructed your request, so it's going to be hard for us to tell what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause of this problem is not setting the API to enabled.

To ensure your API is enabled, you can log into https://code.google.com/apis/console, click on "Services" in the left hand Nav bar and check the service status for Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome. If you find it is set to "Off", that would explain the problem, and you can fix it by setting that to "On".